# Video fullscreen in html5

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am trying to make a fullscrren page with a video.This is my code:

```
 <video  id="backgroundvideo" autoplay controls>
            <source src="{% path video, 'reference' %}" type="video/mp4">

        </video>
```

The css is :

```
  #backgroundvideo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            z-index: -100;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

        }
```

When I am trying to open the page on my phone with android (5 inch) it doesn't work, but opening with Iphone 4 it works.
I think the problem is related to css.

Can you help me fix it or can you give me another solution?

Comment: use http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/

Comment: just a guess: `width:100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top:0;` and without the transformation

Comment: on portrait it's not fullscreen on android with 5inch

Comment: Why you edited out the android tag? Is your question not related anymore to android?

Comment: actually it's about html and css.the css is the problem

Comment: Well as long your html/css issue occures ***only*** on Android device your question ***is*** related to Android.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't say HOW it doesn't work, I'm not sure how to help you. However:

```
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
```

If you are going fullscreen, why position the video 50% down, and 50% to the right? top: 0; left: 0; seems more logical. Am I missing something?

```
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
```

Not sure what you want here, but fullscreen == full screen, so why tell the browser it can decide for itself how to size the video? If you want full screen, 
width: 100%; height: auto;  should do. Mind you, because the ratio may be different than your screen's, you may get bars top/bottom. But I think that's better than stretching the video anyway.

I'm not sure, I don't do a lot with video and support is very spotty across the board, but I think your code may simply be confusing the browser.

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Are you counteracting the 50%? Why?

Anyway, whatever the issue really is here, video support is simply one of those things that are still well and truly in the 'browser war' realm. Everybody does things their own way.

Look into this solution for serving compatible video to (almost) all. It also comes with fairly decent CSS to steal... I mean, 'learn from'. ;-)

http://mediaelementjs.com/